# Populate a Razor view from two models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using entity framework in MVC. I have two models that populate from a SQL table using DBContext

```
public class Incident
{
  
    public Guid IncidentKey { get; set; }
   
    public int IncidentID { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{           
        public Guid RequestKey { get; set; }
      
        public int RequestID { get; set; }
}
```

Below is how I am getting the the data to pull from SQL

```
public class CallViewerDbContext : DbContext
{
    
    public DbSet<Incident> Incident { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Request> Request { get; set; }

}

public class SqlData : IIncident, IRequest
{
        private readonly CallViewerDbContext db;

        public SqlData(CallViewerDbContext db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }}



 internal static void RegisterContainer(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
        {

   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterType<SqlData>()
                .As<IIncident>()                 
                .InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<SqlData>()
               .As<IRequest>()
               .InstancePerRequest();       
        builder.RegisterType<CallViewerDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        httpConfiguration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

I am trying to create a new model that will will allow me to get a count for both of the entity's when I put it on a new Razor view. I am currently able to get one by using the below method.

```
 IIncident db;

    public HomeController(IIncident db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = db.IGetAll();
        return View(model);
    }

  public IEnumerable<Incident> IGetAll()
        {
        return db.Incident;
        }
```

I have tried making a new model.

```
public class DataModel
{

    public List<Incident> allIncidents { get; set; }
    public List<Request> allRequests { get; set; }

}
```

I tried adding it to the Register Container

```
 builder.RegisterType<SqlData>()
                  .As <IDataModel>()
                  .InstancePerRequest();
```

Then updated the Home controller

```
    IDataModel db;

    public HomeController(IDataModel db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = db.MGetAll();
        return View(model);
    }

  public IEnumerable<Incident> MGetAll()
        {
        return db.Incident;
        }
```

I am trying to return the data using the MGetAll method to get the list of Incidents, I then have a another method that does the same for requests. I was trying to return individual counts to the view first then add in the second.

I am now getting the below stack trace error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[CallViewerData.Models.Incident]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CallViewerData.Models.DataModel]'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `builder.RegisterType<SqlData>()
                  .As <IDataModel>()
                  .InstancePerRequest();` `SqlData` doesn't implement that interface.

Comment: Did you recompile the code?

Comment: Your view is expecting an `IEnumerable<DataModel>`. You aren't passing it that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = PrepareViewModel();
    return View(model);
}

private DataModel PrepareViewModel()
{
    return new DataModel
    {
        allIncidents = db..., // Get Incidents
        allRequests = db... // Get Requests
    };
}
```

And in your view

```
@model namespace.DataModel
```

Then you can access them with `Model.allIncidents` and `Model.allRequests`.